# Efficient way to implement rather than structures in Matlab

Tags: matlab, structure

I am reading some data from a csv or text file ( which consists of thousands of rows with each row consists of fixed number of columns - e.g.: 20).

I am keeping the above details in matlab with a structure as follows.

```
initial_var(firs).second_var(sec).third_var(thir).time(end+1, :) = [];
initial_var(firs).second_var(sec).third_var(thir).scan(end+1, :) = [];

initial_var(firs).second_var(sec).third_var(thir).time(end+1, :) = val1;
initial_var(firs).second_var(sec).third_var(thir).scan(end+1, :) = val2;
```

where `first`, `sec`, `thir`, `val1`, `val2` are filled from the csv/text file.
There are multiple fields available other than `time` and `scan` but I have not included them here.

While running the program, I am getting the warning

> The variable `initial_var` appears to change size on every loop iteration. Consider preallocating for speed.

I know this can be solved by preallocating and initializing.

But my question here is, what is the better way of keeping the above data rather than the above mentioned structure type?

Answer (score 1):

These lines won't do anything:

```
initial_var(firs).second_var(sec).third_var(thir).time(end+1, :) = [];
initial_var(firs).second_var(sec).third_var(thir).scan(end+1, :) = [];
```

It means "delete the row after the end of this array".

You might like to look at a multi-dimensional structure:

```
vars(firs,sec,thr).time(end+1, :) = val1
vars(firs,sec,thr).scan(end+1, :) = val2
```

Should be easier to initialise too.

Also, when loading the data, you might like to look at [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html).

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the fastest and most flexible way to read data is with `fscanf`. (See also `csvread` for a convenience wrapper for csv files.) For example:

```
data = randn(1e4, 20);
save data.txt data -ASCII

tic
h = fopen('data.txt')
data_read = fscanf(h, '%f');
data_read = reshape(data_read, 1e4, []);
toc
```

```or-tag-here
Elapsed time is 0.089097 seconds.
```

If the data are all numeric, then it is fastest to store and operate on simple matrices.

Also, if you post some specific data and reproducible code, we might be able to give more specific answers...